# Deleted the file I tried to commit, no message

Tags: git

I'm a new user trying to commit and push my first `.md` file.  I screwed up and tried to commit without a message, giving me a fatal error and landing the file in both the staged and unstaged areas.

Online advice said to remove it.  I tried rm and got the same fatal error message.  Other online help said "physically remove" the file, and not being sure what that meant I deleted it and emptied the trash.

I don't need the file.  I"m happy to start over.  I Just need to clear the mess and start again.

I tried to reset, I tried rm cached.

Here's what shows in git gui, in the yellow field in the northeast quadrant:

```
Staged for commit, missing <file>
deleted file mode 100644
@@ -1 +0,0 @@
-## This is a markdown file
\ No newline at end of file
```

git status says on branch master, initial commit, changes to be committed: (use "git rm --cached to unstage), then it lists the deleted file as a new file in green, then changes not staged for commit, a new suggesting to add/rm or checkout (all tried), and it lists the deleted file in red.

The error message I get is

```
fatal, unable to create project/.git/index.lock: file exists.
```

Then it says that if no other git process is currently running, it's likely that a git process crashed in this repo earlier, and it suggests I physically remove the file.

I'm using git bash as per my Coursera instructions, and it doesn't let me copy text the way I'm used to.  I also have git gui, and I'm checking that against the git bash output.  It's all new to me.  I'm sure I missed some parentheses and/or quotation marks as I tried to type what I saw in the error messages.

I don't know what a shell is.  I'm using Windows 7.

I don't have any other files in this repo and could start over.  Not sure how to delete a repo but I can look it up if that's the fix.

Comment: What is the output of `git status`? Also, could you please add the error message that you're getting?

Comment: Thanks for editing your question. May I ask what shell and OS you're using? You should be able to actually select, copy, and paste the output from your terminal. Wait, is this cygwin, or msysgit/Git Bash? Also, do you have any other files that you want to keep in this repo? You could manually remove the `index.lock` file, but I'm not sure how safe that is if you don't have any backups, in case something goes wrong. Also, you're not using TortoiseGit too, are you?

Comment: Check out [merlin's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23208727/456814). Also, if you're using Git Bash, then you can copy text by select with the left mouse button, then right-clicking to copy to clipboard. You might need to enable "QuickEdit" and "Insert" mode by going into `Properties > Options` first though. You can select Properties by right-clicking on the terminal window (a shell is a terminal program). I know, it's kind of complicated. It's actually easier if you develop using a Mac instead of Windows...better Mac support for these sorts of things.

Comment: I added instructions for how to copy and paste from you terminal in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23208942/456814).

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned that this is your **first** commit. If you want to just clean up **completely**, the easiest way to do it is to `cd` to your directory (inside `git bash`), remove the `.git` directory, and start running your instructions from the start.

**Warning**: This will delete your *entire local repository*, so make sure you truly do not need it.

```
rm -rf .git
```

If you are on a purely local repository, and you want to re-initialize, you can do:

```
git init .
git add MyFile.md
git commit -m "Commit Message"
```

Comment: Merlin, will the first instruction, deleting my entire local repository, delete the untracked files?  I think not, but better check.

Comment: @user3558400, No, it only deletes stuff in the repository, not in the current working directory. In some sense the `.git` directory IS the repository.

Comment: I tried it and got the same fatal error, Unable to create 'C:/users/shannon/.git/index.lock': File exists.

Comment: @user3558400, Did you `cd` into the directory `C:/users/shannon` and do `rm -rf .git` from there? Also, if you do this *immediately after a reboot*, it is less likely that you will be fighting with another process for a lock on the file.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like your biggest issue was the fact that it looks like git ended up
crashing and left you with a dirty `index.lock` file that needed to be cleaned
up. Since you didn't have anything else in the repository, you can either
delete that file, located under the `.git` folder of your project, or you can
just remove the entire `.git` folder, as suggested in [merlin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23208727/456814).

However, assuming that you didn't have that `index.lock` problem, here is how
you can fix your issue if it happens again. I've replicated the steps you
described, and I ended up with this:

```
$ git status
On branch master

Initial commit

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)

        new file:   readme.md

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        deleted:    readme.md
```

You can either commit your readme file from here (since it's already staged),
or you can choose to check it out into your working copy again. The working copy
doesn't really matter at this point, because all that matters for a commit is
what's in the staging area.

Given the above, you can do the following in any order...no matter which order
you choose, you'll get the same result:

```
git commit -m "Your commit message"
git checkout -- readme.md
```

### How to Copy & Paste From Terminal

Here is some un-related but useful instructions for copying and pasting from
Git Bash, since you were having trouble with it earlier.

1. Right-click on your Git Bash window at the top, then select `Properties`.

   [image]
2. Under `Options` select both `QuickEdit` and `Insert` modes (I'm not actually sure if you need both, but I have them both on, and everything works fine for me):

   [image]
3. Hold left-mouse button and select the ***area*** that you want to copy:

   [image]
4. Right-click to copy the selected area to your clipboard. You can now paste it wherever you want:

   ```
   $ gs On branch master

   Initial commit

   Changes to be committed:
     (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)

           new file:   readme.md
   ```

Comment: I tried both commands, and got the same fatal error I get every time.  Unable to create 'C:/users/shannon/.git/index.lock': File exists. So it does look like the issue is the dirty index.lock file.  I put it in the trash yesterday, emptied trash, restarted the computer... is there another way of deleting files?

Comment: @user3558400 it sounds like there's some process/program running that has the `index.lock` file open. Try restarting your computer (to shutdown all programs and processes), then when it finishes restarting, immediately delete the file again. If that doesn't work, then I'm not sure :(

Comment: Partial success! On another thread I found this command "rm -f ./.git/index.lock", which untangled the pathway mess.  Now I have nothing in staged changes, but I still have a missing file in unstaged changes and an unhappy yellow box on the git gui.  Getting closer.

Answer (score 0):

The error message "Unable to create 'C:/users/shannon/.git/index.lock': File exists" was related to the dirty file Cupcake described this way: "So it looks like your biggest issue was the fact that it looks like git ended up crashing and left you with a dirty index.lock file that needed to be cleaned up."

The fix was rm -f ./.git/index.lock.  That alone allowed me to resolve the other issues.